# How to determine if a Doctrine entity is persisted?

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is there a way to determine if a parameter is an object that is already persisted by Doctrine or not? Something like an entity manager method that checks that an object is not a plain old object but actually something already in memory/persisted.

```
<?php
public function updateStatus(Entity $entity, EntityStatus $entityStatus)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
    try {
        // checking persisted entity
        if (!$entityManager->isPersisted($entity)) { 
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Entity is not persisted');
        }
        // ...
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

EDIT: As said by @Andrew Atkinson, it seems

```
EntityManager->contains($entity)
```

is the preferred way now.

Previous answer: You have to use UnitOfWork api like this:

```
$isPersisted = \Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork::STATE_MANAGED === $entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityState($entity);
```

Comment: UnitOfWork is marked @internal. This usually means that you are advised to remove the usage or replace it with other construct. Using `EntityManager->contains($entity)` should be preferred

Comment: EntityManager->contains($entity)  is returning 1 but flush comand returns 500 error, any suggestions?

Comment: Contains does not seems `saved` in database!!!

Answer (score 46):

The `EntityManager` method `contains` serves this purpose.  See [the documentation (2.4)](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#_contains).

In Doctrine 2.4, the implementation looks like this:

```
class EntityManager {
// ...
public function contains($entity)
{
    return $this->unitOfWork->isScheduledForInsert($entity)
        || $this->unitOfWork->isInIdentityMap($entity)
        && ! $this->unitOfWork->isScheduledForDelete($entity);
}
```

Comment: This is the answer!

Answer (score 7):

An Easier and more robust way to check if the entity is **flushed** or not, just check for the ID.

```
if (!$entity->getId()) {

    echo 'new entity';

} else { 

    echo 'already persisted entity';

}
```

This solution is very much dependant on the case, but it may be the best for you

---

edit:

From comments it appears this is not the most relevant answer, however may provide useful for someone as it is closely related to the question.

Comment: Does persisted objects already have id ? I thought it was the case for flushed ones only

Comment: @arnaudbey I think this is the case, which makes the answer almost irrelevant. will edit answer

Comment: This will not work when using Postgresql database with Doctrine : when persisting entities to the entity manager and id is attributed to the entity. In this case (use of postgresql), you can check that an entity is persisted, not if it is **flushed** as you mentioned in your answer...  To escape the differences between usage of db, the API should be used.

Comment: This would not work with mock objects (e.g. in tests) where I set an ID.

Comment: I noticed that in the PrePersist lifecycle event, the id is already assigned before the entity has been persisted and flushed. You cannot rely on the id!