# Detect if an object is an entity (without interfaces)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity, symfony-2.3

#### for example i have this entity.

```
<?php

namespace AcmeDemo\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Test
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="test")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Test implements IEntity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

#### And thats the interface.

```
<?php

namespace AcmeDemo\UserBundle\Entity;

interface IEntity
{
    public function getId();
}
```

#### Then i can check the object via

```
$object = new Test();
if ($object instanceof IEntity) {
    echo 'Yes, its an entity.';
} else {
    echo 'No entity detected!';
}
```

But if i have no interface declared i cant do this.
And define the IEntity on each Entity is bad, too.

What can i do instead the example above?

**Thank you in Advance! :)**

Comment: Why are you think that define the IEntity on each Entity is bad? I think it's a good solution if you don't want to use Interface

Comment: Why is it that you don't want to use an interface?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if a Doctrine entity is persisted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613684/how-to-determine-if-a-doctrine-entity-is-persisted)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the doctrine annotation reader and search an "Entity" annotation on the class.

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;

$annotationReader = new AnnotationReader();

//Get class annotation
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('My\Class');
$classAnnotations = $annotationReader->getClassAnnotations($reflectionClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to detect if an object is a entity but assuming you're using Doctrine, you can use the following:

`$em->getMetadataFactory()->hasMetadataFor('AcmeDemo\UserBundle\Entity\Test')`

The `hasMetadataFor` only check for Doctrine metadata. If you want to be sure it is an entity, you can compute it with:

```
$meta = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor('AcmeDemo\UserBundle\Entity\Test');
$em->getMetadataFactory()->isEntity($meta);
```

Comment: isEntity() is protected method